# What is an example of Var(XY) (as opposed to Var(X + Y))

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

I'm reading [Probability: For the Enthusiastic Beginner](http://a.co/5ZxjJ6g), and he explains that `Var(X + Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y)` for independent variables. His example is, if you have a coin toss where H = 1 and T = 0, `Var(X)` is 1/4, so `Var(X + Y)` would be **two independent coin tosses** and so `Var(X + Y) = 1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2`. That makes sense, I can read `Var(X + Y)` as "X and Y". But then what does `Var(XY)` mean in this coin toss example? I don't see how I could multiply one coin toss by another?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ represent independent coin tosses, then $XY=0$ for the three cases $\{HT,TT,TH\}$ and $XY=1$ for the case $HH$ (as $H=1,T=0$).  As the four cases are equiprobable you can compute mean and variance accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you read $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)$ as variance of $X$ **and** $Y$? Just take the notation literally: $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)$ is variance of $X$ **plus** $Y$. Then, similarly, $\operatorname{Var}(XY)$ is the variance of $X$ **times** $Y$. To compute it, observe:

- $XY$ can only take on 2 values $1$ and $0$
- $XY=1$ when both $X$ and $Y$ are 1; that is, $XY=1$ iff both independent tosses turn heads, which happens with probability $\frac{1}{4}$
- $XY=0$ in the other 3 cases: $(X,Y)\in\{(1,0),(0,1),(0,0)\}$.

Thus, so $XY$ follows the Bernoulli distribution with probability $\frac{1}{4}$ of getting $1$ and probability $1-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$ of getting $0$. It follows that:
$$
E(XY)=\frac{1}{4},\quad\operatorname{Var}(XY)=\frac{1}{4}\frac{3}{4}=\frac{3}{16}.
$$
You can of course compute $E(XY)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(XY)$ directly (without appealing to knowledge of the Bernoulli distribution:
$$
E(XY)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1+\frac{3}{4}\cdot 0=\ldots,\quad E[(XY)^2]=\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1^2+\frac{3}{4}\cdot 0^2=\ldots,\\ \operatorname{Var}(XY)=E[(XY)^2]-[E(XY)]^2=\ldots
$$